# Neo4j GC overhead limit exceeded when deleting nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, garbage-collection, cypher

I am trying to delete nodes with their relationships with the following code:

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
match (a:AppointmentType)
with a limit {limit}
detach delete a
return count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

and I get the following error: 
    `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` .

I have used the same code previously and didn't have any problems.

I am not sure why I am getting this error because I am limiting the batch size to 10000.

I have also tried without `apoc.periodic.commit` :

```
match (a:AppointmentType)
with a
detach delete a
return count(*)
limit 100
```

and the query runs for a long time and after that I get the same error.

Does anyone know how to avoid this error?

Comment: Have you tried lower batch sizes?

Comment: Yes and the result is the same

Comment: In your second query, the `limit 100` should be after `with a`, otherwise you're only limiting the number of count rows (which will always be 1 anyway, as an aggregation) instead of limiting the number of nodes matched and deleted.